# Determinant of product of matrix and vectors

Tags: determinant

In determinants, we have the property that $det(AB)=det(A)det(B)$, I believe this can also be extended to the product of three matrices i.e. $det(ABC)=det(A)det(B)det(C)$.

---

Given $X$ is a vector of order $nx1$ and $X'AX=0$ where matrix A has appropriate order.
So $det(X'AX)=0$, this implies that $det(X')det(A)det(X)=0$.
But X is not even a matrix, let alone be a square matrix, a necessary condition to define determinants.
Where did my reasoning go wrong?

Comment: the determinant of a matrix product is the product of the determinants *for square matrices*

Comment: To add to JW's comment, you may be interested in the [Cauchy-Binet formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula), which gives a method for computing the determinant of a product of general rectangular matrices

Comment: thankyou for stating the correct fact @J.W.Tanner

Comment: Thankyou @twisted_manifold provding further reading material